# What OS does the MS Surface Book use?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, windows-10

I have software that works on various Windows7/10 machines. It does not work on the Surface Book (new, no modifications other than installing MS Office 2016) running Windows10, whether in PC mode or not.

What are the differences between the Surface Book and the desktop/laptops that this works correctly on? If it is many, is there a list somewhere?

("does not work" is off topic here, but if I find out that yes, the Surface Book uses Windows10 Mobile, r some hybrid, which is different in these [x,y,z] ways from the Windows10 on my desktop computer, then I will know what question to ask next)

Comment: Surface book uses desktop version of Windows 10 mostls Windows 10 Pro. It does not use windows 10 mbile. So your question is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only questions related to windows 10 mobile must be asked here. You can use Super user instead.

Comment: As @KolappanNathan said, this question is about a PC running the x86 version of Windows 10, and therefore belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com). This site is specifically about smartphones running Windows Phone or Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: You have answered my question. I had no intent to ask an off topic question, and I apologize for messing up your site. Would you prefer I delete the question, or would you prefer to? By the way, SuperUser didn't like my original question, because I couldn't specify the OS/processor/chip of the SurfaceBook, especially when switching to and from PC mode, and so I had to delete that question. I know that my entire situation is off topic for SO, but I since I don't know of a better place to ask for help, that may be my last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surface Book runs the PC version of Windows 10 (generally Windows 10 Pro). It does not use Windows 10 Mobile, Windows 10 for IoT, or any other non-PC-focused build of Windows. It uses Intel x86-64 processors (not ARM chips like a phone, IoT device, or Windows RT tablet). It cannot install phone apps (unless they are also available for PC), but it should be able to run any PC software that doesn't either require 16-bit support (no 64-bit version of Windows can directly run 16-bit applications, due to a processor limitation) or special hardware.